# Is eval(Expr(:call,m.f,x)) good Julia?

Tags: eval, julia, higher-order-functions

I was hoping for some guidance whether this idiom here

```
h(x) = x^2

type mytype
    f::Function
end
function doit(m::mytype,x)
    eval(Expr(:call,m.f,x))
end

m = mytype(h)
doit(m,3)
```

is good julian when I want to programmatically evaluate a function. So, I have a function `f` stored in some type, and at a certain point I want to evaluate it.

Comment: what's wrong with just `f(3)`?

Comment: yes sorry i just edited the question to be a bit closer to my use case.

Comment: Functions inside of types is not really good julia.

Comment: @Oxinabox can you elaborate please? that's the kind of thing I'd like to learn about.

Comment: A function stores inside a type is a common anti-pattern from people who come from a Object Orientated, languages. They get a single dispatch Method this ways. The more julia ways is like your `f(m::mytype, x)`, rather than `m.f(x)`. Because then the function is open to extension via multiple dispatch.
This is just a rule of thumb, though. Its not a hard and fast "This is always a bad idea".

Comment: As a rule of thumb, `eval` in a function is _almost_ always not what you want to use.

Comment: yes so i guess for my use case it is not so bad an option. I have a user give me an (unknown) function `f`, and I want to carry this around somewhere. Ideally I'd have an object, yes, and in the absense of that I store it on a type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m.f(x)` seems to be just as good as `eval(Expr(:call, m.f, x))`:

```
h(x) = x^2

type mytype
    f::Function
end
function doit(m::mytype,x)
   m.f(x)
end

m = mytype(h)
doit(m,3)
```

also, you don't need `doit` and can just call `m.f(3)` directly, at least in your particular example:

```
h(x) = x^2

type mytype
    f::Function
end

m = mytype(h)
m.f(3)
```

Comment: mmh, I'm a bit confused now. I don't remember why i used that contrived expression to start with! of course you are right, I can call it directly. turns out to be a stupid question :-)